# Como Fazer Hibernate Criar uma Foreign Key de forma Elegante

Tags: java

Estou estudando o hibernate, como a tecnologia dele funciona para criar tabelas e campos. Observei que quando se trata de uma foreign key, ele cria um nome não representativo, que calculado de alguma forma.

Com isso,não terei visibilidade alguma quando uma Exception ou erro de lógica venha ocorrer.

Como posso fazer para conseguir criar o nome da foreign key de forma elegante ?

Answer (score 2):

Uma das formas que funcionou esta abaixo :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cur_profcodigo", referencedColumnName = "prof_codigo", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CUR_PRO_FK"))
private Professor professor;
```